# Substring query/filter in Kibana 3

Tags: regex, elasticsearch, kibana

I have a challenge in creating a query/filter in kibana3. Below is the input and my expected output. Any help is appreciated.

**Input field (countingGroup) has:**
delivered|com.abc.tech.techno.hk.inv_mf|Technology1|Hong Kong|Order|2015-03-09
delivering|com.xyz.tech.techno.au.asn_mf|Technology2|Singapore|Order|2015-02-23
failed|com.def.tech.techno.au.inv_mf|Technology3|Wetherill Park|Despatch|2015-04-08

**Expected Output:**
delivered|Technology1
delivering|Technology2
failed|Technology3

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/hI8nS9/1